# Create image link in html using Google Apps Script in email (html) body

Tags: google-apps-script

I'm trying to dynamically generate a image link for a youtube video with the code above:

```
var emailMessage = HtmlService.createTemplateFromFile("bdaycard");

var msgMate = {};
msgMate.msgNiver = msgNiver;
// ...
msgMate.linkVideo = getURL_(getVideosArt["id"]); //some youtube id video
    
emailMessage.msgMate = msgMate;

var message = emailMessage.evaluate().getContent();

MailApp.sendEmail(emailAddress, subject, emailMessage, {
      htmlBody: message,
}); 


function getURL_(videoId) {
  
  var urlVideo = "https://www.youtube.com/embed/" + videoId;
  var thumVideo = "https://i.ytimg.com/vi/" + videoId + "/hqdefault.jpg";
  
  var urlA = '<a href="' + urlVideo + '" target="_blank" <img src="' + thumVideo + '" width="480" height="360"></a>';
  
  return urlA;
}
```

And my html page is configured  with scriptlets as bellow

```
<div>
 <?= msgMate.linkVideo ?>
</div>
```

Unfortunately as a result I'm getting the text instead of an image link as desired

[image]

There is a way to show the image instead of the snippet code in the final html/body email result?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your script, how about the following modification?

#### From:

```
var urlA = '<a href="' + urlVideo + '" target="_blank" <img src="' + thumVideo + '" width="480" height="360"></a>';
```

#### To:

```
var urlA = '<a href="' + urlVideo + '" target="_blank"> <img src="' + thumVideo + '" width="480" height="360"></a>';
```

And also,

#### From:

```
<div>
 <?= msgMate.linkVideo ?>
</div>
```

#### To:

```
<div>
 <?!= msgMate.linkVideo ?>
</div>
```

- In your HTML, at `<a href="' + urlVideo + '" target="_blank" <img`, the tag `a` is not enclosed.
- In this case, please use `<?!=` instead of `<?=`.

#### Reference:

- [Force-printing scriptlets](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/html/templates#index.html_5)